# JSON extract value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have this data in a table:

```
{ "keys": [ "00170000007u8uJ" ] }
```

I need to extract only the value `00170000007u8uJ` in a SQL Server 2016 select query.

Comment: So how to get that value? The particular column has combination of string, xml..etc so I thought it is xml. The datatype used for that column is ntext

Comment: Add the SQL Server version to your question.

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
declare @json           nvarchar(max)=N'{ "keys": [ "00170000007u8uJ" ] }';

select [value] from openjson(json_query(@json, N'$.keys'));
```

If the JSON is in a table then like this

```
create table #temp_json(json_col        nvarchar(max));
insert #temp_json(json_col) values (N'{ "keys": [ "00170000007u8uJ" ] }');

select [value] 
from
  #temp_json tj
 cross apply
  openjson(json_query(tj.json_col, N'$.keys'));
```

Comment: Where can I add the table in your query?

Comment: @Vinay, and of course, specify your table name instead of `#temp` in the `FROM` clause. Note that the query will return multiple rows when the array has multiple keys. Also, the query will fail if you pass invalid JSON (e.g. an XML value).